# c# Thread.Sleep make program lag

Tags: c#

Hello i have a program with the follow code

```
            oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOnline;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusAway;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusInvisible;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
```

For some reason when it is running the program lag but when i stop the lag stop.
The lag is not from the computer because another programs still running Wheel.
What can i do to stop the lag?

Comment: remove those `thread.Sleep`s!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary this code is in a time if i do that it will be changing to fast

Comment: what stops you from using a timer like System.Timers instead?

Comment: You can async the code.

Comment: @itsme86 i am new what is async the code?

Comment: u r suppose to use a separate thread if u wanna introduce delay

Comment: Google "c# async".

Comment: What part of `Sleep` don't you understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lag is probably caused by the fact that the UI cannot respond while the UI thread is sleeping. If using an async method fixing this is quite easy with `Task.Delay`. `Task.Delay` sets a timer to go off later and then the method resumes. This keeps the UI thread responsive:

```
oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOnline;
await Task.Delay(20);
oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb;
await Task.Delay(20);
oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusAway;
await Task.Delay(20);
oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusInvisible;
await Task.Delay(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding more on what it is oyu are doing, the answer is pretty straightforward. Let us look at msdn documentaton for Thread.Sleep:

> **Thread.Sleep Method** (Int32)
>      .NET Framework (current version) Other Versions 
>   Suspends the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.

Knowing this, the lag is expected, since you are stopping the current thread for a specific amount of time, in this case 20 ms.

Comment: What i want to do is when the timer start it will run the code and i want the program to wait 20ms  between every `oSkype.CurrentUserStatus `

Comment: @Pedro And if you do that on the UI thread; it makes the program "lag". Have to do it on another thread or use async/await and Task.Delay

Answer (score 0):

The user [itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86) indicated me to search for async and i found this youtube [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqlggK6Y7c8)

What i did was create this static task

```
        private static Task<int> SleepAsync(int MS)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(MS);
            return MS / 1000;
        });
    }
```

then i only needed to do was where i want to make the program wait add async and then on the code `await SleepAsync(1000);`

Example:

```
    private static Task<int> SleepAsync(int MS)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(MS);
        return MS / 1000;
    });
}
        private async void StatusLoopTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusOnline;
        await SleepAsync(1000);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusDoNotDisturb;
        await SleepAsync(1000);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusAway;
        await SleepAsync(1000);
        oSkype.CurrentUserStatus = TUserStatus.cusInvisible;
        await SleepAsync(1000);
    }
```

Comment: There is already a method to do this, `Task.Delay`. It uses a timer so it is more efficient than sleeping a thread.